# Changing workspace in Eclipse sets theme and layout to default

Tags: eclipse

How to prevent that?

I want to keep my theme and layout accross workspaces. Is it possible?

Comment: The theme settings are separate for each workspace and should stay the same for that workspace once they have been set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your workspace preferences to a file and import those preferences into each of your new workspaces.